# If statement where all the conditions equal each other

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I need the if statement to only execute if the 5 value in the statement are the same.
e.g if a[0] = a[1] = a[2] = [a3] = [a4] = 1

This is just a matter of boolean algebra but I cant get it right.

I've tried:

```
if( (A[0]) && (A[1]) && (A[2]) && (A[3]) == (A[4]))
        {
            Flag =1;
        }
```

and

```
if( (A[0]),(A[1]),(A[2]),(A[3]) == (A[4]))
        {
            Flag =1;
        }
```

and

```
if( (A[0]) == (A[1]) == (A[2]) == (A[3]) == (A[4]))
        {
            Flag =1;
        }
```

But none of these work.

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Is A of type boolean?

Comment: If a bunch of booleans all need to be true, that's just conjunction `a[0] && a[1] && ... && a[N]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several people have given you the right answer; here's an explanation of why your attempts didn't work.

**Why `A[0] && A[1] && A[2] && A[3] == A[4]` didn't work:**

The expression `A && B` will evaluate to 0 if either `A` or `B` are zero, or to 1 if both `A` and `B` are non-zero.  The `&&` operator is left-associative, meaning expressions like `A && B && C` are parsed as `(A && B) && C`; IOW, `C` is AND-ed with the *result* of `A && B` (0 or 1).  Thus, `A[0] && A[1] && A[2] && A[3] == A[4]` will only evaluate to true if all of `A[0]` through `A[3]` are non-zero *and* `A[4]` == 1, or any one of `A[0]` through `A[3]` are 0 *and* `A[4]` == 0.  Also note that the `&&` operator won't evaluate the right-hand operand if the left-hand operand is 0.

**Why `(A[0]),(A[1]),(A[2]),(A[3]) == (A[4])` didn't work:**

The comma operator evaluates each expression in sequence, and the result is the value of the *last* expression, so only the value of `A[3]` is being compared to `A[4]`.  Each of `A[0]` through `A[2]` is evaluated, but the result is discarded.

**Why `(A[0]) == (A[1]) == (A[2]) == (A[3]) == (A[4])` didn't work:**

Similar to the `&&` operator, the result of `A == B` will be 0 or 1.  Also similar to the above, the `==` operator is left-associative, so `A == B == C` is parsed as `(A == B) == C`, so `C` is being compared to the result of `A == B`, which will be either 0 or 1.  So the above will only evaluate to true if `A[0]` and `A[1]` are the same, and `A[2]` through `A[4]` all equal 1.

Therefore, if you want to check that multiple expressions are all equivalent, you must write something like

```
A == B && B == C && C == D
```

Comment: But note that the && operator guarantees that the left operand is sequenced before the right one, while the == operator gives no such guarantee. This matters when the operands contain side effects such as modifying a variable or calling a function. For example, `a++ && a++` is well-defined behavior, but `a++ == a++` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

From boolean logic we have `if A == B AND A == C then B == C`

In C/C++ you can not combine the evaluation of an expression, so each condition has to be done individually.

So you can do it like this:

```
 if( (A[0] == A[1] && A[0] == A[2]  && A[0] == A[3]  && A[0]== A[4])
     flag = 1;
```

If this is an array you can do it in a loop as well like this (pseudocode):

```
 v = A[0]
 flag = 1; // Asume that all are equal.
 for(i = 0; i < maxindex; i++)
 {
      // If one entry doesn't match the whole expression is false.
      if(v != A[i])
      {
           flag = 0;
           break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. :) It would be nice if you accept the answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Each comparison needs to be done individually.

```
if (A[0] == A[1] && 
    A[1] == A[2] &&
    A[2] == A[3] &&
    A[3] == A[4])
{
    Flag = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this happens to be an array, you could take advantage of that:

```
const int N = 4;
bool everything_is_equal = true;

for(int i=0; i<(N-1); i++)
{
  if(A[i] != A[i+1])
  {
    everything_is_equal = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Depending on the number of elements, this may or may not be more readable than a long if statement using the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is:

```
if( A[0] == A[1] && A[1] == A[2] && A[3] == A[4] && A[4] == A[5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than for booleans, there is no general way to write this shorthand.  You'll need to do something like:

```
if (A[0] == A[1] && A[1] == A[2] && ...)
```

or something equivalent, or encapsulate this behaviour in a helper function (something like `bool areAllTheThingsEqual(T *things, int num)`).

Answer (score 0):

that would check if all are equal A4 which would mean all 5 are equal:

```
if( A[0] == A[4] && A[1] == A[4] && A[2] == A[4] && A[3] == A[4] )
{
         Flag =1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add something, you may study the operator priority first;
 (1) "==" and "&&" which one is first
 (2) May cause some compilation error
 (3) Notice that "==" OPERATOR will return true or false you cannot connect them together
If you want to explore, you can try to use xor to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

As was stated, this is the usual way

```
if ( A[0] == A[1] && A[1] == A[2] && A[2] == A[3] && A[3] == A[4] )
{
    Flag = 1;
}
```

Your first attempt however made me think of an alternative way, using bitwise logical operations, since `&` and `|` on equal numbers gives the very same number.

But as soon as some of the numbers are different, i.e. there is some bit set to 0 in some number and 1 in another, `|` will yield 1 and `&` will yield 0 on this position in the resulting numbers, making them different.

```
if ( (A[0] & A[1] & A[2] & A[3] & A[4]) == (A[0] | A[1] | A[2] | A[3] | A[4]) )
{
    Flag = 1;
}
```

This seems to run about twice as fast (under `-O2` optimisation)

Comment: `==` binds  more tightly than &` and `|` (yes, it's counterintuitive, but we're stuck with it), so you need parentheses. And how long do you expect the reader to spend understanding the condition? I'm not even sure I do.

Comment: Thanks, I had the parentheses there while testing. And honestly, I do not expect anyone to actually use this.